# How to get records created at the current month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a candidate which has_many votes.

I am trying to get the votes of a candidate that were created in the current month?

```
@candidate.votes.from_this_month

scope :from_this_month, where("created_at > ? AND created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month)
```

That gives me a PG error:
PG::Error: ERROR:  column reference \"created_at\" is ambiguous

If I try

```
scope :from_this_month, where("vote.created_at > ? AND vote.created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month)
```

I get the following error

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "vote"
```

Comment: Try `votes` with an S

Comment: Not related to question, but `Time.zone.now` is preferable to `Time.now`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enclose the where in a lamda as well.

```
scope :from_this_month, lambda { where("votes.created_at > ? AND votes.created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month) }
```

Otherwise it may appear to work and your tests will all pass, but if your app runs for more than a month you will start to get incorrect results because Time.now is evaluated when the class loads, not when the method is called.

Answer (score 12):

Correct scope

```
scope :from_this_month, lambda {where("votes.created_at > ? AND votes.created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month)}
```

This is because in rails the model names are singular(i.e `Vote`) and tables created are pural (e.g. `votes`) by convection

**EDIT**

This can be written simpler with `lambda {where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month..(Time.now.end_of_month))}` and we need to use lambda due to the reason given in below comments.

Thanx  *BroiSatse* for reminding :D

Comment: This can be written simpler with `where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month..(Time.now.end_of_month))`

Comment: This won't work correctly because Time.now will be evaluated when the class is loaded, not when the method is called. It should be enclosed in a lambda

Comment: Thanx *bridiver* I have corrected the answer now. Didn't thought of that issue

Answer (score 6):

From Rails 5 you have a much cleaner syntax. On your votes model add a scope `this_month`

```
 scope :this_month, -> { where(created_at: Date.today.all_month) }
```

You can now query `@candidates.votes.this_month`

Comment: I've been using Rails for 5 years and never seen this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
  scope :this_month, -> { where(created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now.end_of_month) }
```

and you can call the scope:

`Model.this_month`

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [ActiveRecord Association Extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
#app/models/Candidate.rb
Class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :votes do
       def from_this_month
           where("created_at > ? AND created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month)
       end
   end
end
```

This should allow you to call `@candidate.votes.from_this_month` to return the required conditional data