# Rails Date.today is reflecting Date of Deployment of Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, amazon-ec2

I have a rails application where it displays active EVENTS (Events on or after today).

`scope :active, where("event_date >= ?", Date.today).order("event_date ASC")`

It is coming fine on local. But on production server , the query is taking the Date of deployment for comparison.

This is the log

`SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."school_id" = 32 AND (roster_id in (45) or roster_id IS NULL) AND (event_date >= '2014-09-18') ORDER BY event_date ASC`

But if check from console on production, it is showing correctly

```
 1.9.3-p448 :001 > Date.today
     => Fri, 19 Sep 2014
```

Server is on AWS EC2

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get records created at the current month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423079/how-to-get-records-created-at-the-current-month) although this question has a better title that might be more relevant for people searching for the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting it in a lambda:

```
scope :active, -> { where("event_date >= ?", Date.today).order("event_date ASC") }
```

Probably `Date.today` is being evaluated at the time when the code is loaded(i.e. deployed).

Comment: Yes, this is the reason where *lambda* is must needed. Good answer +1